# Why is destructor invoked

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor

This is a code I have been trying to understand how it works.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int variable;

    A()
    {
        cout << "Default Constructor\n";
    }

    A(int variable_)
    {
        cout << "Overloaded Constructor\n";
        variable = variable_;
    }

    A(A& Object)
    {
        cout << "Copy Constructor\n";
        variable = Object.variable;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        cout << "Destructor\n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    {
        A* PA1 = new A(1);

        cout << "\n";

        A* PA2 = &(A(*(PA1)));

        cout << "Second\n\n";

        A* PA3 = &(A(1));

        cout << "\n";

        A* PA4 = new A(*(PA3));
    }



    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Why is destructor called after initialization of `PA2`? What does this mean - `&(A(*(PA1))) and &(A(1))`?

This is output of this code:

[image]

Comment: And you didn't get any warning like "taking address of tempororary"?

Comment: *why is destructor called* -- Your output is lacking.  You should be outputting the value of `this` to understand or get an idea **which** destructor or constructor is being invoked.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie i did it but A* PA2 = &(A(*(PA1))); by declaring PA2 like that it calls destructor for same adress as PA2's one! i don't know what is really going on here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&(A(*(PA1)))` calls `A(*(PA1))` and returns a pointer to the variable. Because this is a constructor, it returns a variable of type `A`, and because you are passing it a variable of type A, it calls the copy constructor. This is not good code, because the return is in temporary memory. The behavior for this is undefined, so you should never use this when writing code.

`&(A(1))` does the same thing as above, but calls the constructor that takes an int, because that is what you are passing to it.

The reason the destructor is called is because C++ automatically destroys variables that are unused/whose scope expires. So when you call the constructor without using the `new` keyword, the object is created, but you don't store it anywhere; you store its address, which as stated above is undefined behavior. So the value returned by the constructor (called temporary for this reason) is immediately destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are temporary objects and get killed when they are out of scope.

&(A(*(PA1))) means an address of an object of A, which is constructed with copy constructor with input variable pointed to by PA1.

&(A(1)) means an address of an object of A, which is constructed with copy constructor with input variable 1.

In both cases these objects are temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `A* PA3 = &(A(1))` creates a temporary object, which will be destroyed right after the statement. Hence, the destructor will be called at this point, i.e. right after the statement.

It seems as if you struggled with the fact that `PA3` will still point to the address of the (destroyed) temporary object.

Note that in C++, destroying an object does not change/reset any pointer to this object. It is just defined that accessing a deleted object through such a pointer invokes undefined behaviour. So it is not surprising that `PA3` points to the same address as the `this` of the temporary object. Dereferencing this pointer, however, will yield undefined behaviour.